# Typescript not finding types from module's index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 4.2.3, I am building a package from Typescript. When I install the package, its entry in `node-modules` has `.js` and `.d.ts` files, as expected.

```
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.test.d.ts
│   └── index.test.js
└── package.json
```

Here is the content of the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "postgres-base-class",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "description": "Abstract class to handle an Postgres Client connection, provding execSql method to extending classes",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
<omitted>
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "prepack": "npm run clean && npm test && tsc --declaration",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "author": "John Bito",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true
}
```

When I try to extend the class defined in the package, the protected method's parameters and return type are shown as `any` in VSCode, and `tsc` does not detect erroneous parameters. Instead, it appears to be treating the package as a JS package without types.

What can I do to make the types in the package available to `tsc` where the package is installed?

Here is the content of `index.d.ts`:

```js
import { Client, QueryConfig, QueryResult } from "pg";
export type { QueryConfig } from "pg";
declare class ConnectURI {
    uriPromise: Promise<string>;
    uriString?: string;
    constructor(uri: Promise<string>);
    uri(): Promise<string>;
    toString(): string | undefined;
}
export default abstract class BasePostgresClass {
    connection?: Client;
    connectURI: ConnectURI;
    constructor(uri: Promise<string>);
    protected execSql(query: QueryConfig): Promise<QueryResult>;
    private connect;
    close(): Promise<void>;
}
```

The type of the `execSql` method where the package is imported seems to be (according to VSCode):

```
execSql(query: any): Promise<any>
```

That matches the content of `index.js` produced by `tsc` (excerpted):

```js
class BasePostgresClass {
    constructor(uri) {
        this.connectURI = new ConnectURI(uri);
        console.debug("Got a promise for connection string");
    }
    async execSql(query) {
        console.debug("Executing query", query);
```

Comment: Can you share content of "dist/index.d.ts" ?

Comment: The full contents of index.d.ts and the relevant lines from index.js are now in the question, @theanurin.

Comment: Does `pg` contains its types build-in, or are you using a separate package for them in the `devDependencies`? If it is a separate package, probably you have to move it to `dependencies`.

Comment: Hi @KingGary! That was it!!! Would you like to add it as an anwser, so I may accept it?!

Comment: @John, I'm glad I could help you. I have added it as the answer. Thanks, and good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the `pg` dependency of the `postgres-base-class` dependency is getting shadowed by the `pg` dependency of the main project.

- If your main project imports `pg` explicitly, add `@types/pg` to your main's `devDependencies`.
- If not, ensure `pg` is NOT in the main project's dependencies (to avoid it shadowing the child's dependency types), and add `@types/pg` to your `postgres-base-class` [dev]dependencies

[Working from `yarn add ../relative`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKTmd.png)

Comment: While the gist of this is reasonably accurate, the `devDependencies` of `postgres-base-class` include `@types/pg` (obviously). It is made to work when the **`dependencies`** of `postgres-base-class` include `@types/pg`.

Comment: To add to my answer, it shouldn't matter much on either project (main or child) if it's on dependencies or devDependencies, as long as it ends up in the same `node_modules` folder as where TS finds `pg` : i.e. if main doesn't require it, it should be pulled by child's dependencies; if main depends on it, main should also include @types/pg to avoid it shadowing the @types dependency even if present under child.

Comment: You got it working when you added it to `dependencies` of `postgres-base-class` only because dependencies are pulled in when you depend on it from another package, and not when it's on `devDependencies`; that's why my example use it from relative import (since it did `npm install` on the child too, which pulled in dev-dependencies), but if you're just importing the external build, it needs to be in dependencies or [dev]Dependencies of main. `tsc` does NOT look [dev]dependencies fields of packages, it only look on the node_modules tree.

Answer (score 1):

Does `pg` contains its types build-in, or are you using a separate package for them in the `devDependencies`? If it is a separate package, probably you have to move it to `dependencies`.

Comment: While this is what enabled me to resolve the problem, it's really not an answer. I'll give it an up-vote because it deserves credit, but I'll write an answer if you don't have time, @KingGary.